# CoreData crashes when fetching data in loop

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I'm working with old `xcdatamodel`, it was created in xcode 7.3 (that's a crucial since I don't have the following issue on modern models). At the same time, this issue is not cured by simple changing `Tool Version` to `Xcode 9.0` for my `xcdatamodel`.

I'm fetching data in `for` loop, in the thread of context I use for fetching data. When I try to fetch the entity that has already been fetched once, coreData crashes with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP)`. Zombie tracking says `[CFString copy]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x608000676b40`.

This is the concept of what I do:

```
LegacyDatabaser.context.perform {
    do {
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let entity = try self.legacyDatabase.getEntity(forId:1)
            print(entity.some_string_property) // <- crash here
        }
    } catch {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here is the context initializer:

```
class LegacyDatabaser {
     static var context: NSManagedObjectContext = LegacyDatabaseUtility.context
     // ...
}
```

And

```
class LegacyDatabaseUtility {
    fileprivate class var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        //let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType:.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        //context.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
        //return context // This didn't help also
        return storeContainer.newBackgroundContext() 
    }
    private static var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name:"MyDBName")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()
}
```

Here is the data fetcher:

```
func getEntity(forId id: NSNumber) throws -> MyEntity? {

    // Create predicate
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"id_local == %@", id)

    // Find items in db
    let results = try LegacyDatabaseUtility.find(predicate:predicate, sortDescriptors:nil, in:LegacyDatabaser.context)

    // Check it
    if results.count == 1 {
        if let result = results.first as? MyEntity {
            return result        
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And:

```
static func find(predicate:NSPredicate?, sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor]?, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> [NSManagedObject] {

    // Create a request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName:"MyEntity")

    // Apply predicate
    if let predicate = predicate {
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    }

    // Apply sorting
    if let sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors {
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    }

    // Run the fetchRequest
    return try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
}
```

I don't address the context somewhere in a parallel, I'm sure I use the correct thread and context (I tested the main context also, the same result). What I'm doing wrong, why re-fetching the same entity fails?

Comment: Unrelated but consider to return a **non-optional** on success and `throw` an error on **any** failure in the `getEntity()` method. And the `results.count == 1` check is redundant, `first` returns `nil` if the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone catches any quirk crashes like one I described above, check the name of properties in your `NSManagedObject`. In my case, crashes were on call `new_id` property which is, I guess, kinda reserved name. Once I renamed this property, the crashes stopped.